# Segfault copying from file to string with fgets()

Tags: c, string, file, eof, fgets

I have a text file which has days, time, hours, dates as below:

```
aaaa rrr rrr rrr 1111111111111111 2222222222222222
aaaa rrr rrr rrr 3333333333333333 4444444444444444
bbbb rrr rrr rrr 5555555555555555 6666666666666666
bbbb rrr rrr rrr 6666666666666666 7777777777777777
cccc . . . . .
.
.
.
```

The `aaaa` and `bbbb` are i.e. `0001` `0002` and so on, the `rrr` lines are irrelevant and the `11...11`, `22...22` etc. are dates and time, i.e. `2005-11-03 04:50`.

So, I have 3 malloc'ed arrays of strings:

- sip for `aaaa`, `bbbb` etc.
- std for `11..111`, `33..33` etc. (first line)
- etd for `22..222`, `44..44` etc. (second line)

What I want to do is store:

- all different aaaa, bbbb in sip[number_of_them]
- the `11...11` in std[number_of_them]
- the `44...44` in etd[number of them]

NOTE: for example --> `aaaa` in sip[0], `11...11` in std[0] and `44...44` in etd[0].

Every time the `aaaa` changes to `bbbb` and so on --> `bbbb` to sip[1], `55...55` to std[1] and `77...77` to etd[1]

Unfortunately, something is causing segfault in my code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

main () {

    char** sip = malloc(count*sizeof(char*));            // Array for storing flight combinations
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) sip[i] = malloc(5);

    char** std = malloc(count*sizeof(char*));            // Array for storing starting time and date
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) std[i] = malloc(17);

    char** etd = malloc(count*sizeof(char*));            // Array for storing ending time and date
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) etd[i] = malloc(17);

    char* temp = malloc(5);     // Temporary string for passing over irrelevant charactersf

    int a=0, lines = 1;

    char str[2];
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "rb");{
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            fgets(sip[a],  5, fp);                // SP is stored

            fgets(std[a], 14, fp);                // Pass over irrelevant characters
            fgets(std[a], 17, fp);                // STD is sotred

            fgets(etd[a],  2, fp);                // Pass over irrelevant characters
            fgets(etd[a], 17, fp);                // Temporary ETD is stored

            fgets(temp, 3, fp);                   // Pass over newline
            fgets(temp, 5, fp);                   // SP is stored to check if it has changed

            while (strcmp(temp, sip[a]) == 0) {   // Check if SP has changed
                fgets(etd[a], 16, fp);            // Irrelevant characters
                fgets(etd[a], 16, fp);            // Irrelevant characters

                fgets(etd[a++], 17, fp);          // Correct ETD is stored here, starting from 31st character
                fgets(temp, 3, fp);               // Pass over newline
                fgets(temp, 5, fp);               // SP is stored to check if it has changed

            }
        }
    }

printf(" %s \n %s \n %s \n ", sip[0], std[0], etd[0]);        // Printf to check result    

}
```

A sample text file is shown below:

```
0021 918 ATH SKG 2011-11-02 20:00 2011-11-02 20:55
0021 901 SKG ATH 2011-11-03 05:00 2011-11-03 05:55
0022 518 ATH HER 2011-11-02 20:00 2011-11-02 20:50
0022 501 HER ATH 2011-11-03 05:00 2011-11-03 05:50
0023 325 ATH CAI 2011-11-02 22:50 2011-11-03 00:45
0023 326 CAI ATH 2011-11-03 01:45 2011-11-03 03:45
0024 301 ATH TLV 2011-11-02 23:15 2011-11-03 01:10
0024 302 TLV ATH 2011-11-03 04:00 2011-11-03 06:10
0025 530 ATH CHQ 2011-11-01 03:50 2011-11-01 04:40
0025 531 CHQ ATH 2011-11-01 05:20 2011-11-01 06:10
0026 175 ATH SKG 2011-11-01 07:05 2011-11-01 08:00
0026 175 SKG MUC 2011-11-01 08:40 2011-11-01 10:45
0026 176 MUC SKG 2011-11-01 11:35 2011-11-01 13:35
0026 176 SKG ATH 2011-11-01 14:15 2011-11-01 15:10
```

And the expected answers are:

```
0021 2011-11-02 20:00 2011-11-03 05:55
0022 2011-11-02 20:00 2011-11-03 05:50
0023 2011-11-02 22:50 2011-11-03 03:45
0024 2011-11-02 23:15 2011-11-03 06:10
0025 2011-11-01 04:40 2011-11-01 06:10
0026 2011-11-01 07:05 2011-11-01 15:10
```

Comment: Do the lines always occur in pairs like that?

Comment: yeah, in pairs of 2, 4 or 6 at most.. and when I say pairs I mean pairs of aaaa, bbbb, cccc and so on, which are in reality text like 0021, 0022 aso.

Comment: So of these groups of 2, 4, 6 lines with the same first value, what exactly do you want to extract? Is it the first date from the first line and the last date from the last line of the group?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract `aaaa` then the first [date and time] `11..11` and then the last [date and time] `44..44`. Then `bbbb` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void die(const char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s.\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main() {
    char line[256];

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) die("Can't open file");

    // Count the number of unique first values.
    int count = 0;
    char sp[5], sp_last[5] = {0};
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        sscanf(line, "%4s", sp);
        if (strcmp(sp, sp_last) != 0)
          ++count;
        strcpy(sp_last, sp);
    }
    rewind(fp);

    char (*sip)[5]  = malloc(count * sizeof(*sip));
    char (*std)[17] = malloc(count * sizeof(*std));
    char (*etd)[17] = malloc(count * sizeof(*etd));
    char etd_in[17];

    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) == NULL)
        die("Can't read first line");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%4s %*s %*s %*s %16c", sip[i], std[i]) != 2)
            die("Can't scan line (a)");
        std[i][16] = '\0';
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
            if (sscanf(line, "%4s %*s %*s %*s %*16c %16c", sp, etd_in) != 2)
                die("Can't scan line (b)");
            etd_in[16] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(sp, sip[i]) == 0)
                strcpy(etd[i], etd_in);
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        printf("%s %s %s\n", sip[i], std[i], etd[i]);

    free(sip);
    free(std);
    free(etd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the answer! But it doesn't work as I want it to. I will update the initial post with a sample text file. What you wrote prints correctly the `sip` array of strings, but then it prints the other values incorrectly... Check the initial post for the expected answer, thanks again!

Comment: I didn't know your date field had a space in it. Fixed. (Please tell me I didn't just do your homework for you!)

Comment: Thanks for the update. No, I'm learning C and I haven't understand fully how this whole fopen, fgets, fgetc works :) That's why I play arround trying to fully understand how they work...

Comment: Read the documentation for fopen, fgets, fgetc etc. And don't do `while(!feof....`

Comment: OK, I will revise :) , I've read it, but you know if you don't practise, you can't figure it out all by yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that one problem (at least) is here:

```
char** sip = malloc(count*sizeof(char*));            // Array for storing flight combinations
for (i=0; i<count; i++) sip[i] = malloc(5);

char** std = malloc(count*sizeof(char*));            // Array for storing starting time and date
for (i=0; i<count; i++) sip[i] = malloc(17);

char** etd = malloc(count*sizeof(char*));            // Array for storing ending time and date
for (i=0; i<count; i++) sip[i] = malloc(17);
```

You allocate three arrays of strings `sip`, `std`, and `etd`, but then you only initialize the elements of `sip`, three times each. The second `for` loop should probably initialize `std` and the third should initialize `etd`.

Comment: Ow, thanks for noticing that, I copy-pasted wrong.. My bad, thanks anyway!